# Weird unsigned char * concat behavior

Tags: c++

I've got two unsigned char arrays, and a char array. I want to xor both unsigned char arrays and then join a char array.

```
char mensaje[] = "A";
unsigned char key[] = "61181d3cfd91b0cc0890c2c0646c94f692b311ffbf93749c0aadd8ae6f04f044";
test(key, mensaje)



void test(unsigned char key[],char mensaje[]){

        unsigned char   pad_exterior[64];
        unsigned char   pad_interior[64];
        for(int i =0 ; i<64; i++ ){
            pad_exterior[i]= 0x5c ^ key[i];
            pad_interior[i]= 0x36 ^ key[i];
        }


    char * result = new char[strlen(mensaje)+ 64];
    copy(mensaje, mensaje + strlen(mensaje), result);
    copy(pad_interior, pad_interior + 64, result + strlen(mensaje));


    char * result2 = new char[strlen(mensaje)+ 64];
    copy(mensaje, mensaje + strlen(mensaje), result2);
    copy(pad_exterior, pad_exterior + 64, result2 + strlen(mensaje));
}
```

The problem is, at the end, strlen(pad_exterior) = 65 but strlen(pad_interior) =1.

However, if I replace

```
pad_interior[i]= 0x36 ^ key[i];
```

with

```
pad_interior[i]= 0x36;
```

it does work.

Why this odd behavior?
Is there a better way to accomplish what I am trying to do? I've tried over a dozen ways to copy the arrays.

Edit:
I figured I needed char arrays because I am calling [EVP_DigestUpdate](https://linux.die.net/man/3/evp_digestupdate).
The test function basically just xor and joins the arrays. 
The call is at the beginning of the code

Comment: How do you call this `test` function? Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us? Also, if you're programming in C++ don't add the C tag.

Comment: Also, `strlen(mensaje)` will always be `1`. And if you 're programming in C++, why are you using simple arrays instead of `std::string` and `std::vector`?

Comment: Check the value of `0x36 ^ '6'`.

Comment: I've edited the question.

Comment: You may also be missing a step where you convert the key from a hex digit string form to actual bytes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`strlen` is designed to work with *null terminated* `char` arrays. It uses the `\0` terminator to actually find the length.

So if `0x36 ^ key[i]` is `0`, your `pad_interior` becomes null terminated too early.

And if `0x5c ^ key[i]` is **never zero** your `pad_exterior` is not null terminated. And you run into UB when you do `strlen(pad_exterior)`. You were just a little lucky that it returned 65.

Comment: woow, what should I do then?

Comment: @Gaston Use `std::string` which can have nulls in the middle.

Comment: In the code, pad_exterior is correctly used as a fixed length buffer.  It is just your "debugging" check which is wrong.  You can't use strlen there, but it is fine on the actual plaintext, which is a null terminated string..

Comment: @Gaston, I just noticed that the code you posted doesn't correspond to your question. You never actually call `strlen` on either `pad_interior ` or `pad_exterior `.

Comment: Sorry, I was just calling it in the debugger.

Comment: This answer is still correct, because the question was why is my binary data not looking right when I try to read it as a null terminated string (which it isn't).

Comment: @Gaston, well here's your problem. Consult your debugger manual for how to watch a fixed size buffer. And don't use `strlen` where you are not supposed to :)